# odoo auto publish product

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to build an automation rule in Odoo 11 (enterprise) so my products can publish and unpublish on the website automatically.

We sell seasonal products, roughly 17.000, and we do a lot preparation in advance. 
So with "scheduling" (un)publish a product, we can save a lot work and automate this job.

So far with all my attempts, it's not working. 
I have created 2 custom fields for model product.template:
x_publish_start and x_publish_end

I have created an automated action with trigger condition "based on timed condition" and apply it to products where x_publish_start is SET (not empty). 
Trigger date = x_publish_start

In the data to write, I have set the default field visible on website = TRUE

Basically, this should work?? But it's doing nothing in my end.

The condition is quite basic:
if today() >= x_publish_start -> publish product
if today() >= x_publish_end -> unpublish product

screenshot
http://sharing.codeagency.be/0c0d7512e9f9

Anybody who knows what is wrong with my concept and automation, or can provide a working code example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those actions get triggered when editing a record (see action to do: update the record). What you need is more a cron that runs every day (or hour, minute...) and publishes/unpublishes products that match (or not) current date. The model you're looking for is `ir.cron`.

Comment: are you sure about this? 
The trigger condition is time based, and trigger date = x_publish_start so basically this is  a time based automation. 

See here the other options:
http://sharing.codeagency.be/a1ef328ac9d1

As you can see, the option "on create and/or update" is not used. 
So this is really a time based condition. 

Can you give me an example for ir.cron how to do this?